# use CSS:before to separate anchors

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<a href="a.html">A</a>
<a href="b.html">B</a>
```

I want to have the result:

> [A](http://a.html) - [B](http://b.html)

so I made this CSS:

```
a:not(:first-child)::before{
 content: ' - ';
}
```

the jsFiddle [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/t44o72ch/).

But this puts the dash in the second anchor, effectively like so:

```
<a href="a.html">A</a><a href="b.html"> - B</a>
```

but I'm looking for:

```
<a href="a.html">A</a> - <a href="b.html">B</a>
```

Needless to say is that the links are dynamically generated, so hardcoding it like this is not an option. Can this be done in CSS and if so, how?

Comment: so this can't be done with CSS?

Comment: Why just not `<a href="a.html">A</a> - <a href="b.html">B</a>`?

Comment: @Vucko: "Needless to say is that the links are dynamically generated, so hardcoding it like this is not an option"

Comment: @patrick sorry, misread that. What about putting the links in `li`, and then use `::before` on them - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cwrzx47/1/).

Comment: @Vucko: that's a very useful approach indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I would want to do it outside of the anchors, I would wrap each anchor inside of a span and apply the before to the span element:

```
<span><a href='a.html'>A</a></span>
<span><a href='b.html'>B</a></span>
```

Here's the fiddle with spans working: http://jsfiddle.net/8w2onc74/2/

Comment: the result of this is the ' - ' "inside" the anchor (like <a href='b.html'> - B</a>). I'm looking for a solution where the ' - ' is in front of the anchor (like  - <a href='b.html'>B</a>)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach! For some reason (personal taste) I like my selector better, this can still be used with your <span> solution though (fiddle updated at http://jsfiddle.net/8w2onc74/2/).

Comment: This can be taken even a step further by using CSS to style the before element into the dash (or a circle or square for that matter) and avoid using the `content` property for a visual separator.  an added advantage is that a screenreader then won't read out "dash" or "hyphen", but also it's a little more semantic, and much more customizable.  updated your fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uxLtshr3/

Answer (score 3):

Technically the `:before` or `:after` will always be *inside* the element it is placed on. *But* we can fake it.

- `pointer-events: none` so that it can't be clicked
- `cursor: text` so that it doesn't look clickable
- `position: absolute` with `left: 100%` to pop it outside the parent `a` which has `position: relative`
- A color matching the normal text color

### Example

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:first-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a:first-child:after {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="a.html">A</a>
<a href="b.html">B</a>
```

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. I'd also notice that `pointer-events` [don't have support for lt IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).